# WPF: Save selected tab in properties settings

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I want to save the current selected tab in `tabcontrol on _Closing`.

So when I start the program again I want the saved tab to be re-opened.

I have tried to read up on `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` but I don't 100% understand it. Or how it shoud be done in my case?

Anyone who can give me a hint?

Comment: You could simply save the that in a local storage or even in your database or even in a simple local file. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried something like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: But I dont understand how I can add the selected.item in tabcontrol to that  properties setting.

Comment: Read the comments below, on that link'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Create a Property in project settings and give it a default value, refer to following image:
   [image]
2. Before closing the application store the index of current selected tab in the property and it can be retrieved next time while loading the application, following is an example:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       //To retrieve the last saved tab index
       String LastSelectedTab = RestoreSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.CurrentSelectedTab;

       Console.WriteLine(LastSelectedTab);

       //To save the current selected tab index
       RestoreSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.CurrentSelectedTab = 2;
       RestoreSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
   }
   ```

   The settings will be saved in the following location and named as user.config:

> C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\YOURPROJECTFOLDER\1.0.0.0

The config file will be like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
  <userSettings>
      <RestoreSettings.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="CurrentSelectedTab" serializeAs="String">
              <value>2</value>
          </setting>
      </RestoreSettings.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer. But I get "The name RestoreSettings does not exist in the current context"

Comment: RestoreSettings is the name of the project I've given to create an example for you. You shall replace it with your project name.

Comment: Thanks. just found that out myself. shoud have tried a little before asking, sorry :)